# the installation tools such as 'make/apt/apt-get/dpkg/rpm' not found in the image 'docker run xxx docker', how to install openssh-service

Tags: linux, docker, sshd

Docker in Docker is great, but the biggest problem for me is failing to use the 'sshd',
I want is using 'docker run xxxx docker' to start a container as a virtual instant. And I want to 'ssh xx@hostIP -p XXX' to connnet this container.

but the image is hard to install 3rd software, because 'make/apt/apt-get/dpkg/rpm' is all not found in the image. It's similar to the 'Linux minimum system'. So how should I install openssh-service and start the service?

thank for your help!

[docker pull docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker?tab=description&page=1&ordering=last_updated)

Comment: `apt` and `rpm` together? at least post your Dockerfile

Comment: Usually you'd only run one process per container, so a dedicated container for this service.  Why do you actually need ssh in this context?  Do you have a Dockerfile or any other source code you can share?  (Are you trying to use the DinD image as a virtual machine for day-to-day work?)